# Editing menus within XFCE

Tags: xfce, customization

I am using Xubuntu 14.04. I would like to customise it to my needs. Just for anxiety I would like to change the Menu Contents of " About XFCE " . I usually change names by editing /usr/share/applications/xfce-about.desktop file . But Now I want to change the contents of it. Where is the coded file ?
Note : For customization I use  ubuntu builder !

I took a look on many links and found these are all what I am doing right now. See we have a menu named "About XFCE " when we click it , it will show up a window . Inside that some contents describing it like  say

> " Xfce is a collection of programs that together provide a full-featured desktop
>   environment. The following programs are part of the Xfce core: "

My requirement is to change this long description in that application. How can I achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

The intro message you quote is hard coded in this xfce4-about file:

http://git.xfce.org/archive/xfce-utils/tree/xfce4-about/main.c

xfce4-about is the program that you are running when you click "About XFCE".  It is part of the xfce-utils package.

As you can see by viewing the above file, the list of core packages is generated programmatically.

Modifying any of this would require modifying the above .c file and compiling your own copy of the xfce4-about program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `alacarte` or `menulibre` to modify the menu entries in XFCE. Try installing one of these:

```
sudo apt-get install alarcarte
sudo apt-get install menulibre
```

I personally recommend the second one.

Answer (score 0):

The [customize-menu](https://wiki.xfce.org/howto/customize-menu) entry at the xfce wiki should answer all of your questions.

> **Customize the Xfce menu**
>
> This page describes how to customize the menu, using Xfdesktop 4.5 or
>   higher. For earlier versions you can use the libxfce4menu GUI.
>
> A GNU-licensed graphical menu editor for LXDE, [LXMenuEditor](http://lxmed.sourceforge.net/), also
>   works for XFCE, as of XFCE 4.8.0 and LXMenuEditor 20110523.

Comment: This isnt I am looking for. I took a look on the link and found these are all what I am doing right now. See we have a menu named "About XFCE " when we click it , it will show up a window . Inside that some contents describing it like  say " Xfce is a collection of programs that together provide a full-featured desktop environment. The following programs are part of the Xfce core: " My requirement is to change this long description in that application. How can I achieve that.